# Does imblearn pipeline turn off sampling for testing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, imblearn

Let us suppose the following code (from [imblearn example on pipelines](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/pipeline/plot_pipeline_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-pipeline-plot-pipeline-classification-py))

```
...    
# Instanciate a PCA object for the sake of easy visualisation
pca = PCA(n_components=2)

# Create the samplers
enn = EditedNearestNeighbours()
renn = RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours()

# Create the classifier
knn = KNN(1)

# Make the splits
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, random_state=42)

# Add one transformers and two samplers in the pipeline object
pipeline = make_pipeline(pca, enn, renn, knn)

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

I want to make it sure that when executing the `pipeline.predict(X_test)` the sampling procedures `enn` and `renn` will not be executed (but of course the `pca` must be executed).

> 1. First, it is clear to me that `over-, under-, and mixed-sampling` are
>    procedures to be applied to the `training set`, not to the
>    `test/validation set`. Please correct me here if I am wrong.
> 2. I browsed though the `imblearn Pipeline` code but I could not find
>    the `predict` method there.
> 3. I also would like to be sure that this correct behavior works when
>    the pipeline is inside a `GridSearchCV`

I just need some assurance that this is what happens with the `imblearn.Pipeline`.

EDIT: 2020-08-28

@wundermahn answer is all I needed.

This edit is just to add that this is the reason one should use the `imblearn.Pipeline`  for imbalanced pre-processing and not `sklearn.Pipeline` Nowhere in the `imblearn` documentation I found an explanation why the need for `imblearn.Pipeline` when there is `sklearn.Pipeline`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Great question(s). To go through them in the order you posted:

> 1. First, it is clear to me that over-, under-, and mixed-sampling are procedures to be applied to the training set, not to the
>    test/validation set. Please correct me here if I am wrong.

That is correct. You certainly do not want to test (whether that be on your `test` or `validation` data) on data that is **not** representative of the actual, live, "production" dataset. You should really only apply this to training. Please note, that if you are using techniques like cross-fold validation, you should apply the sampling to each fold individually, as indicated by [this IEEE paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8492368).

> 2. I browsed though the imblearn Pipeline code but I could not find the predict method there.

I'm assuming you found the `imblearn.pipeline` [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/pipeline.py), and so if you did, what you want to do is take a look at the `fit_predict` method:

```
 @if_delegate_has_method(delegate="_final_estimator")
    def fit_predict(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        """Apply `fit_predict` of last step in pipeline after transforms.
        Applies fit_transforms of a pipeline to the data, followed by the
        fit_predict method of the final estimator in the pipeline. Valid
        only if the final estimator implements fit_predict.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : iterable
            Training data. Must fulfill input requirements of first step of
            the pipeline.
        y : iterable, default=None
            Training targets. Must fulfill label requirements for all steps
            of the pipeline.
        **fit_params : dict of string -> object
            Parameters passed to the ``fit`` method of each step, where
            each parameter name is prefixed such that parameter ``p`` for step
            ``s`` has key ``s__p``.
        Returns
        -------
        y_pred : ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
            The predicted target.
        """
        Xt, yt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
                                 self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
            y_pred = self.steps[-1][-1].fit_predict(Xt, yt, **fit_params)
        return y_pred
```

Here, we can see that the `pipeline` utilizes the `.predict` method of the final estimator in the pipeline, in the example you posted, [`scikit-learn's knn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html):

```
 def predict(self, X):
        """Predict the class labels for the provided data.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like of shape (n_queries, n_features), \
                or (n_queries, n_indexed) if metric == 'precomputed'
            Test samples.
        Returns
        -------
        y : ndarray of shape (n_queries,) or (n_queries, n_outputs)
            Class labels for each data sample.
        """
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')

        neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
        classes_ = self.classes_
        _y = self._y
        if not self.outputs_2d_:
            _y = self._y.reshape((-1, 1))
            classes_ = [self.classes_]

        n_outputs = len(classes_)
        n_queries = _num_samples(X)
        weights = _get_weights(neigh_dist, self.weights)

        y_pred = np.empty((n_queries, n_outputs), dtype=classes_[0].dtype)
        for k, classes_k in enumerate(classes_):
            if weights is None:
                mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)
            else:
                mode, _ = weighted_mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], weights, axis=1)

            mode = np.asarray(mode.ravel(), dtype=np.intp)
            y_pred[:, k] = classes_k.take(mode)

        if not self.outputs_2d_:
            y_pred = y_pred.ravel()

        return y_pred
```

> 3. I also would like to be sure that this correct behaviour works when the pipeline is inside a GridSearchCV

This sort of assumes the above two assumptions are true, and I am taking this to mean you want a [complete, minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this working in a GridSearchCV. There is extensive documentation from [`scikit-learn` on this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-compare-reduction-py), but an example I created using `knn` is below:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

param_grid = [
    {
        'classification__n_neighbors': [1,3,5,7,10],
    }
]

X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.20)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('sampling', SMOTE()),
    ('classification', KNeighborsClassifier())
])

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
mean_scores = np.array(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])
print(mean_scores)

# [0.98051926 0.98121129 0.97981998 0.98050474 0.97494193]
```

Your intuition was spot on, good job :)

Comment: just to clarfify then, if i was to use undersampler, the training set would be undersampled but the test set would contain same proportion of imbalance as before the i undersampled?

Comment: @mathella You can "sample" any dataset you want. Sampling is just a statistical way of adding or removing data. However, you should leave your test set with the imbalance that best reflects what your model would see out in the field. So assuming you split your training and testing data in a stratified fashion and both were representative of your production data, then yes, your training data would be sampled and your testing data not be sampled.

Answer (score -1):

Yes; from [the documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), emphasis mine:

> Sequentially apply a list of transforms, sampling, and a final estimator. Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be transformers or resamplers, that is, they must implement fit, transform and sample methods. **The samplers are only applied during fit.** The final estimator only needs to implement fit. The transformers and samplers in the pipeline can be cached using memory argument.