# Does sklearn pipeline cross-validation resample the training fold data only and remain the hold-out/validation fold unbalanced at each CV fold?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, resampling

For an imbalanced dataset, at each K-fold of cross-validation, I want to do SMOTE resampling for the training fold data to make it balanced, and remain the hold-out/validation fold data unbalanced. Does SKLearn imblearn pipeline (first "resample" followed by "classifier") can achieve that? Does sklearn pipeline will result in balanced out the hold-out/validation data at each fold of cross-validation? I cannot find any official explanations on how the cross-validation + resampling being implemented in sklearn.

I expect to have someone confirm the sklearn pipeline cross-validation + resampling on how to deal with the resampling at each fold. If it is creating balanced data for both training and hold-out/validation sets or only creating balanced data for the training set within each fold of cross-validation remains the hold-out/validation set unbalanced. If possible, please share the code or evidence on it.

Comment: You need to be aware that sklearn's Pipeline and imblearn's Pipeline are different.  imblearn has its own precisely for this reason.  From there, possible duplicate: [Does imblearn pipeline turn off sampling for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520908/does-imblearn-pipeline-turn-off-sampling-for-testing)

Comment: @BenReiniger I have read that thread before, but it is still unclear to me as the answer to question 1 states, "... Please note, that if you are using techniques like cross-fold validation, you should apply the sampling to each fold individually...." if the imblearn's pipeline only resampled the training set within each fold, why the answer says that?